# what does the "am" mean in the git command "git am"?

Tags: git

Does the "am" means "amend"?

But from the document, it just " Apply a series of patches from a mailbox".

So, another guess is: "a" means "apply", "m" means "mailbox"?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely yes. Definitely not amend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The commit that added the original `git-am.sh` script to the git source code](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1c5f2a42d7b5c0e3d3862212dea1f09809c4963) says

> Add git-am, applymbox replacement.
>
> It reorganizes the code and also has saner command line options
> syntax.  Unlike git-applymbox, it can take more than one mailbox
> file from the command line, as well as reading from the standard
> input when '-' is specified.

So I think it's safe to say that “am” is an abbreviation for “apply mbox”.

Note that “mbox” is [a specific mailbox file format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000383.shtml), and the original script used the `git mailsplit` command, which parses the mbox format. So it might be less accurate to say “am” stands for “apply mailbox”.

Answer (score 1):

from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am :
"git-am"
Splits mail messages in a mailbox into commit log message, authorship information and patches, and applies them to the current branch.

Based on this the A would refer to Apply and the M to Mail.